# Linux I/O manager

Tags: c++, linux, io

This is one of those I-don't-know-what-to-call-it so I can't Google it questions.

I s there a Linux (Ubuntu 11.04) library/class/suite that acts to connect my service routines/programs (C/C+) to the network without requiring me to write network access code?  In other words, let's say I have private services I want to offer.  Service 1 serves TCP based messages and replies to the client's source port.  Service 2 serves UDP requests, perhaps to a fixed port on the client regardless of source port.  Service 4 needs to be a TCP client that can send messages/get responses.

The I/O library would have to be told what protocol to use, to serve or be a client, IP addresses to use/honor/reject, security protocols, etc.  It would also need to know how to contact whatever program I hooked to it, i.e. service_1, service_2...  Signals? Callbacks? D-bus?

Any ideas?  Suggestions?  Extra points for cross-OS solutions.

Thanks,

Comment: Are you talking about "sockets"?

Comment: To Tio Pepe:  I just found ICE, but I note it is GPL.  Hard to use GPL in a closed system.  Sigh.

Comment: Oli Charlesworth:  Well, sockets in the sense the tool would open and maintain the sockets it uses to talk to whatever.  I want my code to say things like server = MakeIoServer( "TCP", SERVER, port_3333, ... MyCallback, ... )  and IoServe( server, dataContents, options... )

Comment: I finally decided that D-bus is relly my best choice, only to have it architected out from under me.  Having to do it the hard way and create sockets classes.  Oh well, it should be reusable.  Thanks @SteveC and all!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another widely used message-passing system is [D-Bus](http://dbus.freedesktop.org/doc/dbus-tutorial.html)

Answer (score 3):

You may want to look into [libcurl](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/) if you're looking for data I/O across a network without having to delve into the POSIX sockets interface.  This is of course assuming the protocol you're wanting to use is supported by cURL (it supports quite a number of different network-based data-transfer protocols).

Comment: I always thought libcurl only handled http(s). It seems I learned something new today! +1

Answer (score 1):

Look at [Ice](http://www.zeroc.com/overview.html)

Easy to use, cross-OS, multiple languaje support, etc. A good choice for communications.